# Eclipse refactor pull up

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I have many classes (B0, B1, B2... B#) all extending class A

After initially overriding a function of A and implementing it in all of the B classes. I realise I could have been smarter and implemented it in class A, and now wish to move the function up into it.

Is there a simply way in which I can either remove all the the overrides from the B classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what version of Eclipse you have, you can right-click on the class(es) and go to Refactor => Pull Up.  I tried it in Juno.

Comment: I would prefer not to have to do this 100 times if I have 100 classes.

Comment: You can do it at the project or package level, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a find/replace with a regex:

```
find    - @Override\s*modifier\s*returntype\s*methodname\s*\(.*\)\{.*\}
replace - (blank)
```

(In my regex, replace `modifier` with `public`/`private`/`protected`, replace `returntype` with the return type, and replace `methodname` with the method name.)

Comment: Unfortunately I simplified the description of my class hierarchy, There is a super class above A, and this method exists in other classes sub-classing that. For example, Imagine if this method was toString() or hashCode()